# How to guess the end of pushdown automata by emptying the stack?

Tags: proof-explanation, formal-languages, automata

> Let language $L=\{\sigma_1w_1c\sigma_2w_2c...\sigma_nw_nc\}$ where:
>   $$
> 1\le n\\
> \sigma_i\in \{a,b\}\\
> w_i\in \{a,b\}^+\\
> \exists i:i\le|w_i|
> $$
>   and at least one condition from the two conditions below holds:
>
> the first $i$ letters of $w_i$ form a different word from $(\sigma_1\sigma_2...\sigma_i)^R$ **OR** $|w_i|=n$.
>
> Build a pushdown automaton which receives $L$ by emptying its stack.

The solution of these two conditions separately is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLwvr.jpg.

As far as I understand in the automata for both condition 1 and condion 2 ($|w_i|=n$) essentially:

1. We build an automaton which simply describes reading $\sigma, w_i, c$ first.
2. Then we guess the $w_i$ which is according to condition 1 or 2.
3. Then we read the $\sigma, c$ surrounding the guessed $w_i$ and the $w_i$ itself.

I'm new to pushdown automata, but it looks like a lot of automata could be solved in such a generic way:

1. Read the words according to some logic described in the problem.
2. guess some "good" word (by using $\epsilon$ connection) and delete it from the stack.

Am I missing something?

Also I don't understand why we need $2$ cases in the solution for each condition. The solutions for each condition look almost identical.

Lastly, I don't understand why in the automaton for the condition $1$ in state $q_5$ we need to read the end of $w_i$ first, then read the "good" $w_i$. Why can't we read the "good" $w_i$ straight after the guess?